# SQL Sum Is Calculating for a unique shift and not for the total week

Tags: sql, sum

I am trying to sum all of the hours worked in a given week for my employees. I have written the code below and even though I have gotten rid of the unique shift IDs, I cannot get SQL to sum the hours worked. The start of a week is on Sunday and the end of a week is on Saturday:

```
Select distinct EmployeeID
, concat(e.FirstName, ' ',e.LastName) as EmployeeName
, DATEADD(wk, DATEFDIFF(wk, 0, s.InTime), -1) as WeekStarting
, (DATEADD(wk, DATEFDIFF(wk, 0, s.InTime), -1) +6) as WeekEnding
, sum(Hours) as HoursWorkedInWeek
from Shifts s 
inner join EmployeePayroll e
group by EmployeeID, e.FirstName, e.LastName, s.InTime
```

I get the total hours worked for a unique shift versus for the entire week.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you want is to include the WeekStarting in your group by clause. You can try something like this:

```
select e.EmployeeID,
    concat(e.FirstName, ' ',e.LastName) as EmployeeName,
    dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, s.InTime), -1) as WeekStarting,
    sum(s.Hours)

from EmployeePayroll e
inner join Shifts s 
    on s.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeID
group by e.Employee_id, dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, s.InTime), -1)
```

I have not tested this. If that's not what you are looking for, you can try a window function.